# not able to invoke chrome browser in eclipse using selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, noclassdeffounderror

```
package webdriverbasic;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Webdriverbasicclass {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Sammy\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

    }

}
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeDriver
    at webdriver/webdriverbasic.Webdriverbasicclass.main(Webdriverbasicclass.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 1 more
```

[exception in thread main java lang noclassdeffounderror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrMGD.png)

its my first program in eclipse with selenium and i got this error and not able to invoke the browser

Comment: You need to add appropriate jars or maven dependecy. See https://www.javatpoint.com/selenium-maven

Comment: I uploaded newer version of selenium jar files "selenium-java-4.7.0" in the classpath, and the program ran successfully

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem with the selenium jar. You havent referenced it properly.
The best option is to create gradle/maven project and add the selenium as depedency.
Here is an example how to add it in maven pom file:

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

The path to webdriver looks OK.

Answer (score 0):

First way:
You should download selenium jar files then add it to your project.
Right click on your project > build path > configure build path
Select java build path > libraries > add external Jars.
browse where you add selenium jars then select it.

Second:
You can create a maven project which is a management tool you can install its plugin from eclipse marketplace.
open pom.xml file in the project then under dependencies, add the following code:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```